# When I closed Blender most of my files self deleted themselves

Tags: blend-files

When I closed Blender because it started lagging most of my files deleted themselves.
I was working on a dragon wing i press separate on the armature bone. The blender app then started lagging so I closed using the red X button. Blender says my files cant be found. Is this a glitch?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Closing Blender or even crashing doesn't delete any files. Could you  clarify what what you are doing and how? Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the procedure and issue. also state operating system, system, system specs and Blender version.

Comment: you should not work in a Temp folder, (especially on Linux where it is automatically deleted on reboot) the files may be erased without notice at any point... Please look into your computer trash bin, it may be there.

Comment: Yep, storing files in the Temp folder is not a great idea.

Comment: @Gorgeous totally agree, however on on a dodgy machine, having tmp file data after a hard crash can be a saviour, on `ubuntu`  edit `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` to add a delay time for auto-deletion of  tempfiles _eg_ `d /tmp 1777 root root 20d`
  will keep them for 20 days.  Similar is also available for other OS's.

Comment: @batFINGER Although it can be a saviour this doesn't change the general advice to the OP that it's not a good idea to use it as directory for regular saving.

Comment: GordonBrinkmann in case English is not your first language, will re-iterate, the comment directed to @Gorgious above is   not in any way advocating to save in temp folder.  It is simply stating the default clear after reboot can be changed. Thankyou.

Comment: Ok thank you but i decided I am going to start over I didn't lose much and I only really lost one file The others were turned into fbx files before they got deleted by blender.